# How do I pass a **void pointer to C function? I am getting a cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer

Tags: c, go, cgo

```
package main

//
// void test(data **void) {
//     Do something here...
// }
import "C"

import "unsafe"

func main() {
    var data *C.void 
    cData := unsafe.Pointer(&data)
    C.test(cData)
}
```

Above is an example of what I am trying to do but I am receiving a run time error stating cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer. How do I resolve this issue? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Go equivalent of `void*` is an `unsafe.Pointer`, there's no reason to declare a value of `*C.void`. The error from your example is not about a Go pointer to a Go pointer (which is a runtime error), you will get an error of `(variable of type unsafe.Pointer) as *unsafe.Pointer`, which cannot compile. Use the type shown in the error:

```
func main() {
    var data unsafe.Pointer
    C.test(&data)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Both answers from @MaBed and you helped solve the problem!!!

Answer (score -1):

When you declare `var data *C.void`, you are saying that `data` are Go pointer type. All pointers in Go are subject of garbage collection.

When passing `&data` to `unsafe.Pointer` another Go pointer is created. Thats what the "*Go pointer to Go pointer*" means. It goes `&data` -> `data` -> `(void)`.

In this case, garbage collector cannot decide when would be the right time to deallocate `data`, because `&data` pointer was passed to C, which can still reach `data` through it.

See [this article](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Passing_pointers) about passing pointers to C.

It's not possible, unless you turn-off some of the cgo checks, which **I would not recommend**.

Comment: Hey! as I stated above your answer and JimB answers resolved my issue. There were other variable I was passing in that I needed to recheck. Really appreciate the help!